# How can I draw lines like below using css?

Tags: css

[image]I want to draw this structure between textboxes. I tried my times but unable to draw.

textbox1---|
           |---textbox2
textbox3---|
           |---textbox4
textbox5---|
           |---textbox6
textbox7---|
           |---textbox8

Comment: What are textboxes? what is the HTML structure? I'm pretty sure you can do something simular using :before :after and borders

Comment: If you'd post your HTML/CSS code containing the textboxes and what you have achieved so far it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 3):

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

div:nth-child(odd)::after,
div:nth-child(even)::before {
  content: '---'
}
```

```html
<div>textbox1</div>
<div>textbox2</div>
<div>textbox3</div>
<div>textbox4</div>
<div>textbox5</div>
<div>textbox6</div>
<div>textbox7</div>
<div>textbox8</div>
```

Comment: How do you know his HTML is like that? Why do you think he can use that?

Comment: "Always choose the easiest way" (c)